# SQL Server Managment objects to read data out of a backup file

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, smo

I have a normal SQL bak up, is it possible to use c# & SMO to read info from a table inside my backup file?

The backup file is a normal SQL .bak backup. (in simple mode)

If SMO is not able to do this, is there any other technology that can assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like demas was correct.

this isn't possible.

I ended up using the description field in my backup to store the extra data i needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think is it possible. The backup file format was created to restore the corrupted data quickly and not have any special header with pointers to each table and record.

As I know you can not even restore one table from backup (if it doesn't belong special filegroup) - only full database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Red-Gate native object recovery](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-olr-native/)